# How can I find all strings between two known values?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want `List<string>` for all strings between `[ ]` in string:

```
 Input = "[first] - [second] > [third] + 5"
```

so I want first, second, third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
List<string> lst=Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<=\[).*?(?=\])")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x=>x.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the previous answer:

```
 static IEnumerable<string> GetListFromString(string stringToExtract)
    {

        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[).*?(?=\])");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(stringToExtract))
        {
            yield return match.Value;
        }
    }
```